# How to resolve spring security core plug in?

Tags: spring-security, maven-3

I am having problem with my exercise in Spring Security. I already declare on my pom file:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and on my maven dependency, the spring security core jar file is there, but upon importing **class UserDetailsService** my eclipse cannot found it. I did cleaning and updating my maven project but nothing happens.

Hope someone can advice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I already did deleting all jar on my local repository. Actually, the error has disappeared but when I run my application it says that:. **Java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifeCycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].Standard stuff[localhost].StandardContext[/myspringsecurity]]**

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment so I will write here. Have you tried to delete local maven repository?